# Laravel OpenAI client doesn't work with List result

Tags: php, laravel, openai-api, chatgpt-api

When i try request throw OpenAI laravel library to model gpt-3.5-turbo and result must be list, library throw Exception

```
WARNING  Undefined array key "choices" in 

vendor/openaiphp/client/src/Responses/Completions/CreateResponse.php on line 45.

TypeError  array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, null given.
```

I tried this request for test

```
use OpenAI\Laravel\Facades\OpenAI;

OpenAI::completions()->create([
                'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
                'prompt' => 'Top 3 reachest peaople',
            ]);
```

Comment: You must initialize the client with your API key:
~~~
```
    $yourApiKey = getenv('YOUR_API_KEY');
    $client = OpenAI::client($yourApiKey);

    $result = $client->completions()->create([
        'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        'prompt' => 'Top 3 richest people',
    ]);
```
~~~

Comment: Nah, it doesn't work. I am already init with my api key. I think problem related with model. It's pretty good works with text-davinci-003 model.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was related to the openai model. I changed the model to text-davinci-003 and it worked.